# Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have uploaded my Laravel project to [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) hosting when I go to the IP address of [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance it give me this error:

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0".
```

I check the PHP version and the current version 7.3. I don’t know what I actually need to do. First the version was 7.4, and then I downgraded it to 7.3.

Comment: Do you get the error when you run `composer install`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the answers below that just silence the warnings. Diagnose and address the root cause instead. In my case, I needed to upgrade to PHP 7.4 because a library I was relying on needed it. And I was using WAMPServer and so needed to do: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339235/why-does-phpinfo-show-version-5-5-9-but-php-v-show-version-7-0#comment1214605_339235

Comment: run composer update
it worked for me.

Answer (score 86):

Follow this trick

1. add this line in **config** object of composer.json file

   "platform-check": false
2. run `php artisan config:cache`
3. then run `composer dump-autoload` in terminal

Comment: this worked, but i had to run autoload first before config:cache. thanks

Comment: I managed to get a different error with this. Thanks! 

I'm using Laravel. In my case, it has something to do with monolog/monolog package. I fixed it by locking the version to 2.2.0 as mentioned in https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/issues/1597

Comment: This shouldn't be the best solution, check my answer below

Comment: this worked for me also, but as mentioned by @w1n78 I had to run autoload before config: cache. anywas thanks

Comment: `composer` was correct. Even though my PHP cli was using the version I was expecting, `php-fpm` was still running on old version, and I had to turn off its service and run the new `php-fpm` version service. Do NOT follow this trick - but actually fix the issue as this'll bite you later.

Answer (score 21):

**Problem:**

Your [Composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composer_(software)) checks the platform requirements (PHP version and loaded extensions) when the autoloader is loaded. If you run the application which does not meet the platform requirements, the application will exit with a message similar to this:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0".

**Solution:**

You could use the easiest way: add `--ignore-platform-reqs` option to `composer install/composer update` to ignore all platform requirements.

Comment: I had this message from Composer with Laravel, only use `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` runs.

Comment: Ignore the platform requirements might not be a good solution in all cases - why not properly fix the problem?

Comment: I am trying to upload my `yii2 application` but unable to do it. I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66988294/6854117) can you please see it ?

Comment: This is a very useful answer, I keep running into this issue when i try to run older php with Laravel Valet. 

Thank you

Comment: This fixed my issue with global composer 

Answer (score 19):

[Hashmat Waziri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65339404/composer-detected-issues-in-your-platform-your-composer-dependencies-require-a/65644131#65644131) is right, but if anybody want to use your platform's version, either Composer requires anything, he/she can set the code, depending on his/her system, into the *composer.json* file like:

```json
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.1.0"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me when using Apache in Ubuntu:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Adjust `php7.2` to your current module.

Comment: I am surprised this is not the top-voted answer

Comment: @Denis That's because this only works if you're serving your app with apache

Comment: @Zoraiz on Ubuntu

Answer (score 12):

Please use *--ignore-platform-reqs* with your composer command.

*--ignore-platform-reqs* will ignore platform dependencies.

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

or

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're like me who had to downgrade the PHP version on your machine (Mac) due to a specific reason and when you run `valet use php --force`, you see the Composer global dependencies require PHP v7.3.0 or higher, then you're in the right place. You can comment out the following three lines temporarily and that shall fix the issue for you when running `valet use php --force` again.

Path: `~/.composer/vendor/composer/platform_check.php`

```php
if (!(PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70300)) {
    $issues[] = 'Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running ' . PHP_VERSION . '.';
}
```

Note: don't forget to uncomment the relevant three lines after you switch to the latest version of PHP.

Comment: I had similar problem. I have project that require PHP5.6 (installed) and laravel with PHP7 or PHP8 (all are installed). Tried your suggestion, but resulted: PHP Parse error:  syntax error in /Users/chika/.composer/vendor/symfony/polyfill-php80/bootstrap.php on line 23

Comment: Thanks, valet use php --force worked well without any additional job.

Comment: Works great, I only used valet use php --force

Answer (score 9):

Actually, this was the only solution that worked for me:

```
composer global update
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 5):

I would reinforce the instruction not to blatantly ignore warnings. Would you ignore a warning on an electric fence telling there was a risk of death if you touched it?

In my case I was trying to get an old application running, using PHP 7.2, so couldn't just change the PHP version.

My solution was fairly simple. Examine the *composer.lock* file to find which package requires the version of PHP reported in the warning. Find that package on packagist.org, look for a version of the package that matches your PHP version, and install it.

E.g.,

`composer require <package>:<version>`

You may need to go through this a number of times. In my case I had to install packages that were wanting PHP 7.4 and those wanting PHP 7.3 before my application was happy.

Comment: This is the right answer if changing your PHP version isn't an option. It doesn't ignore errors and it fixes the causes of the errors.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring is not the right option. You have to upgrade your PHP version. Take into account that by now, we already have PHP 8, so with version 7.2 you are far behind.

#### Linux users

Depending on your distributions, if you are using a [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) derivative like Ubuntu, use this link guide: *[Upgrade PHP version to PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/upgrade-php-version-to-php-7-4-on-ubuntu/)* or just google for it and all will be fine.

#### Windows users

1. If you are using Windows, with Laragon, so all you have to do is
   download the PHP version that you want from
   https://www.php.net/downloads.php. Unzip the folder to
   c:/laragon/bin/php folder and then using Laragon GUI select another version in Menu/php.
2. If you wish to upgrade the global Windows PHP version, you can
   use the [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). This for me
   was one the easiest way of doing it on Windows. For more
   information follow *[Install and Configure PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php)*.

Answer (score 4):

Add below code in `composer.json`

```
"config": {
    "platform-check": false,
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.1.0"
    }
},
```

and run command `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 3):

Open [cPanel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) and type multiphp Manager. After that, select your desired domain and at the top right corner, change the PHP version to 7.3 or whatever you would like. Give it some time and your site will be up and running!

[image: See screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The same problem downgrading from PHP 8.0 to 7.2 needed to run an older project.

How I have fixed my issue:

- Remove the broken dependency (installed previously with PHP 8)
- Unlink the newest PHP version then link the older PHP version (I have used brew CLI to link/unlink `$brew link php@7.2`, but I think you can use any PHP manager app to move to older version of PHP without any problem)
- Then reinstall the dependency

This fixed my problem and allow me to switch between different version without further problems, only requirement is use:

```
composer global update
```

after switching PHP version to refresh global dependencies.

I have no clue about what caused the issue. Maybe something went funny during PHP version switch, but we weren't able to put our finger to the cause of the trouble.

P.S. Our problem was related to "laravel/install" package, uninstalling it required uninstall "laravel/valet" before, procedure isn't changed though, simply we have to reinstall both packages on PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment under the original question, instead of just trying to hide the error or bypass it, It would be better to solve it completely to make sure the app performs the way it should. For that, we have to update the PHP version being used. I got this error in a cloud virtual_machine, so I had access to the terminal from where I installed the required version of PHP to the system.

After that, I switched the active version of PHP from the older version to the newer version.

To do this, I first ran,

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
```

You will then see,

`Module php7.2 disabled. To activate the new configuration, you need to run: systemctl restart apache2`

As mentioned, run,

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Then run,

`sudo a2enmod php8.0`

This will enable the required version.Then run,

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

A more detailed explanation is [available here](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-switch-between-multiple-php-versions-in-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=Alternatively%2C%20you%20can%20run%20the%20following%20command%20to,simply%20press%20ENTER%20to%20keep%20the%20current%20choice.).

Answer (score 1):

So, having struggled with this very problem,

> PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.2.5". You are running 7.1.28

for several hours, and finding that none of the above suggestions worked, I finally discovered that -- at least on FreeBSD systems -- the PHP module required by Apache is not installed by the main PHP package (e.g., "php74-7.4.19"), but instead by a different, module-specific package with its own versioning (e.g., "mod_php71-7.1.28").

Executing *php -v* consults the php package; visiting *phpinfo()* consults the mod package.

The clue to this is to execute *pkg info | grep php* and examine the results to see which packages you have installed. Obviously you have to adjust the above for the packaging system your system uses.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you check your PHP version, while there are different SAPIs in PHP, checking the version in Apache2 SAPI using `phpinfo()` is totally different from checking it from your terminal using `php -v`.

Usually, when you install multiple versions, the OS does not override the old versions, for example, if you have PHP7.4, then when you install PHP7.3 you will have the two versions installed. however, your web server is not capable to manage the two versions at the same time.

In your case, all that you need to fix this issue is to make sure that you are using the right SAPI in the right place.

in your terminal check the version by using `php -v`, make sure that you are using the right version `php7.3` in this case. and in your web server use `phpinfo()` to detect the current version, if it is not php7.3 you will need to enable it by the following command:

```
a2enmod php7.3
```

and if the error you are getting is in installing packages, you can install your package directly using the right bin

```
php7.3 /usr/local/bin/composer require package_name
```

Answer (score 1):

so my solution to this issue was update php version on my mac

1. install php by homebrew like this --> `brew install php`.
2. update homebrew by --> `brew update`
3. is to add installed php to paths

   - you should run these commands:

   - `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
   - `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
   - `export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/lib"`
   - `export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/include"`

then restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are here after facing a similar issue on [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) (nothing to do with Laravel), I solved it by the following:

Error shown to me:

**Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl**

- XAMPP was installed multiple times (without uninstalling the previous).
- I uninstalled the one being shown in programs list.
- restarted the PC.
- then deleted all the directories of XAMPP.
- restarted the PC.
- installed XAMPP again.
- -- that’s all.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on Aapanel on my VPS. I already had the latest version of PHP (PHP 8.1) but still, the error did not go every time I tried to run a composer command. I had many versions of PHP running, I tried all the suggested options but none worked. So I thought that maybe composer was seeing the wrong version of PHP and decided to uninstall lower versions(7.2,7.4) and that solved the error!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to remove old php running on the server.

```
sudo apt remove php<version>
```

then run: `sudo apt autoremove`
when you are done `sudo apt install php<version>`

Answer (score 0):

This helped in my case, If the latest version of PHP is already loaded on the server and you need to target a specific version, use the following directive:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php81___lsphp .php
</IfModule>
```

Alternatively, depending on your server configuration, you might need to use the directive below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php81 .php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command will fix your problem: `composer update`