# Migrate AMAZON MWS to SP-API

Tags: php, amazon-selling-partner-api

i try this code for config for SP-API, here i attached screenshot of error, anyone please help me to fix

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use SellingPartnerApi\Api\SellersV1Api as SellersApi;
use SellingPartnerApi\Configuration;
use SellingPartnerApi\Endpoint;

$config = new Configuration([
    "lwaClientId" => "<LWA client ID>",
    "lwaClientSecret" => "<LWA client secret>",
    "lwaRefreshToken" => "<LWA refresh token>",
    "awsAccessKeyId" => "<AWS access key ID>",
    "awsSecretAccessKey" => "<AWS secret access key>",
    "endpoint" => Endpoint::NA  // or another endpoint from lib/Endpoint.php
]);

$api = new SellersApi($config);
try {
    $result = $api->getMarketplaceParticipations();
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling SellersApi->getMarketplaceParticipations: ',
`your text`        $e->getMessage(),
        PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

getting error like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsuh7.png)

Comment: See this question which has the same error has your screenshot:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65339404/composer-detected-issues-in-your-platform-your-composer-dependencies-require-a